# How to draw/load part of a page that is currently looked at?

Tags: javascript, performance, dictionary

I am currently working on a map generator application based on javascript, and I have wrote more than 400 lines of code, that creates a hexagonal map, adds coordinates to tiles, adds textures on tiles like grass, ocean and elements like castles, units etc.

I have added quite a few useful functions to this offline map editor, like zoom in and zoom out, turning grid on/off, dragging the map, and a few others, and I'm currently studying on how to add save and load functionality to this offline game map editor.

It sort of looks like a paint application, except that instated of drawing pixels, you use it to draw a map with hex tiles. You simply click on Generate a new map and you give your desired map size (e.g 64 tiles width by 64 tiles height) and the map is drawn for you, the tiles are simple divs that have the relative background image as texture. Tiles are drawn one by one using a simple for loop. But as the code grows in size so does my worries.

Because the map I create on my own map editor will be used on an online multiplayer game, it will be huge! for example to support at least 20000 users on the upcoming game there should be at least 20000 tiles, only for the users to occupy, not to mention the territory they will own, mountains, jungles, barbarian tribes, and so on..

I have made the calculations and found out that a 512 by 512 (about 262000 tiles) map will sufficiently answer the needs of that many users. However, the map will be huge. so I decided to test and see how much load time does it take to make such a map using the codes I have created with the least process possible and I found out that it takes nearly a minute or more, which is not acceptable, from a gamers perspective.

A zoom in for example in such a huge map will mean looping through every 262000 tile to change their size. although the process takes less time than drawing/loading the map from scratch, but it is still slow.

I was thinking with a map that huge which won't even fit in a browser's window, why should I draw the entire map? why not instead load the part which the user is currently looking at. Loading/drawing only the part that is needed, this way reducing load time and increasing performance. But this is proving to be a real challenge, and there are very limited resources online about implementing such a functionality. Where to start? How to approach the problem and respective solution?

Comment: So you are reinventing Google Maps, plenty of tutorials online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start out by separating your concerns a little more. You're able to view WxH number of pixels, and the top left of the user's screen sits at (x,y) coordinates. 
Loading the entire map, as you have pointed out, is crazy. But by knowing how large the game world is, and by knowing the user's coordinates in that world, you can easily select the subset of items that are in view.
Keep in mind that at a zoomed out resolution you shouldn't be using the full-sized images. Loading 262000 images (for just the map!) is going to be too heavy and probably crash. You should have different images for different zoom levels. This is a much bigger question and you should buy a book and do more research on google. But at least the thinking about the "where the user is" vs "where the items in the world are" is a place that I would start at.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that's a good hint. I should start thinking about where the user is!

Comment: Also think about drawing the region around the screen if you're doing an active scrolling system because you'll need to have that data loaded as you move into that area. Several years back I did a google maps style messaging system where users could place messages anywhere in a 2d space and it did that exact thing. Good luck!

Comment: yes i was thinking on the same lines. Thanks for the hints again.